# java creating and deleting cookies unexpected behavior

Tags: java, javascript, jakarta-ee, cookies, setcookie

I have a problem with cookies handling using java:

we have a tomcat cluster managed by apache to serve multi application, all on the same domain.

**First problem:**

Creating cookies using java, setting the `cookie.setPath("/")` to cover all domain pages, in order for all applications to be able to read the cookie, the scenario,

1. i'm in `application1`, `app1` creates the cookie, setting the path of cookie, to the `/app1/`
2. moving to `app2`, `app2` can't read the cookie, it creates the cookie with another path, `/app2/`

what is going wrong with ?

**Second problem:**

The perfect code for cookie deletion works fine with me, on our servers, 
but moving out to different servers, the code can read the cookie, so no domain problem there, but can't delete it.

Again what is going wrong with java handling cookie ?

Do i have to use javascript better than java for cookies handling ?

Comment: Without posting code, you won't get far on SO since guessing is quite useless.

Comment: i don't think the problem is with the code, for the first problem,
creating cookie through a servlet embedded into every app, using cookie.setPath("/"), and the creation with wrong weird path, like /app1/ 
for the second the problem, the code for deletion works fine on another environment, and i think while it works, and i can read the cookie on the new enviroment, why deletion fails, may be not with code it self.

Comment: Before you have evidence of the contrary, don't start by believing that the problem is in the JDK / JEE implementation, for a simple feature used by millions. Always question your code first. And if you have to ask on SO, you have to reconsider your assumptions, and we don't have to take them for granted.

Comment: Have you tried a direct request to a Tomcat instance to eliminate an Apache configuration problem?

Comment: could you explain please what do you mean ?

Comment: You have to isolate the cause of the bug. To do so, eliminate all the unnecessary parts, such as the Apache front-end. You never know, the cookie might be correctly set at the Tomcat stage, but incorrectly rewritten by an Apache directive. If your application's context path is not /app1/, for example. So try a direct HTTP request to the Tomcat instance.

Answer (score -1):

You should set the domain, not the path:

```
cookie.setDomain("example.com");
```

Now all applications hosted on `example.com` will be able to share the same cookie. For example applications on `app1.example.com` and `app2.example.com` will be able to see this cookie.

Comment: all apps are accessible through, www.example.com/app1 , www.example.com/app2. actually the domain is settled the righ way as wrote it.

Comment: Then this should work without any problem. I guess the issue's somewhere else.

Comment: note that we have a cluster of tomcat nodes, and an apache server managing these nodes, so every application may reside on some node, but still all accessible by the same domain, would this be a problem ?